# Create a service worker from a foreign origin

Tags: javascript

I'm building a web push notification system that can be integrated on any website. I control these sites, but I'm trying to make the integration as simple as possible so it can be done by someone other than me. Ideally, I could just give someone a single JavaScript or iframe tag to drop in and it would just work.

```
<script src="https://foreign.com/main.js" />
```

-- or --

```
<iframe src="https://foreign.com/main.html" />
```

I first tried to create a service worker from a foreign script - that threw an exception and I've since read up on why. I understand why this doesn't work.

```
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://foreign.com/sw.js')
```

So I tried creating a very simple page that just runs the JavaScript to setup the service worker, and calling that from an iframe. This does appear to work - it asks for permission and creates the subscription. But if I try to send a message to that subscription, nothing happens. It just silently fails. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done, it'll be a security issue, not in the Specs.
SW has to be downloaded from same origin, same path and https

Comment: But the service worker DOES register and the subscription does get created, so this doesn’t answer my question.